# I'm trying to create an anchor on my page without changing the URL. Does anyone have an idea on how I could do that?

Tags: html, facebook

Explaining: I inserted an anchor  right before the facebook plugin for comments and I inserted in the middle of a text a link to the anchor Comment, so when the user clicks the link, he/she jumps straight to the facebook comments, but it keeps adding the #comment to the URL, and the facebook plugin considers it as another page, and all the previous comments disappear. Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: None of them! I thought it was possible to that only with HTML. However, if there's a possibility to do with one or another, it would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this just in your HTML. Add this to your document's `<head>`:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://website.com/path/to/page" />
```

Facebook will realize that `/path/to/page` and `/path/to/page#comments` are the same object and will show the same comments on both.

Just be careful if you are using a CMS. Each unique webpage needs to have a unique a canonical url.

You can also specify a canonical url in your `og:url` metadata for the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the href to "javascript: void();" or something similar.

Comment: I'm going to try that! Thanks!